# Remove duplicate rows from answer of below query

Tags: sql, sqlite

**List all directors who directed 5000 movies or more, in descending order of the number of movies they directed

The use of Distinct before d.name doesnot help.

```
result = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT d.name,count(*) as num 

FROM PERSON d, M_DIRECTOR md 

WHERE d.Pid = md.Pid 

GROUP BY d.Pid,d.name 

HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10

order by count(*) desc

",conn)
```

Comment: I don't think anyone has directed 5,000 movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use proper explicit joins between the tables and count on distinct movies:

```
select 
  p.name,
  count(distinct d.mid) num
from person p
inner join m_director d on d.pid = p.pid
inner join movie m on m.mid = d.mid 
group by p.pid, p.name
having num >= 10
order by num desc
```

Comment: duplicates still not removed

Comment: `group by p.pid, p.name` **by definition** removes duplicate id and names, so either the schema you posted is missing clues (like is there a case that a name in table person appear more than once?), or you are doing something wrong.

Comment: To check if there exist duplicates inside table person: `select count(*) total, count(distinct p.id) total ids, count(distinct p.name) totalnames from person p`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have duplicate records in `Person` table - people with the same name but different ids. Try to group just by name and not by id

```
    result = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT d.name,count(*) as num 

FROM PERSON d, M_DIRECTOR md 

WHERE d.Pid = md.Pid 

GROUP BY d.name 

HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10

order by count(*) desc

",conn)
```